# Should we normalize before using VarianceThreshold in sklearn?

Tags: variance, feature-selection

I am trying to remove features with low variance using [VarianceThreshold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold.html) 
It seems to me that we should normalize the data before calculating variance, but somehow VarianceThreshold is not doing it automatically. Thoughts ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, one must do normalization before using VarianceThreshold. This is necessary to bring all the features to same scale. Other wise the variance estimates can be misleading between higher value features and lower value features. By default, it is not included in the function. One must do it using MinMaxScaler or StandardScaler available in scikit-learn.

Comment: Two answers totally opposite each other!!!

Comment: @MTT pls refer this link (http://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/05/7-methods-data-dimensionality-reduction.html) which mentions the importance of scaling when variance threshold is used.

Comment: @ Thanks a lot! I did my research and agreed with you. Variance calculation without normalization is somehow meaningless especially for numerical features.

Answer (score 4):

The features must have the same units, therefore scaling is necessary (for example reduce the range to [0,1] with the MinMaxScaler).

Standardize for example with StandardScaler, that means removing the mean and scaling to unit variance, is wrong because of course each feature will have variance 1.

Comment: The second sentence seems OK (it makes no sense to normalize--setting the variance to 1--before checking whether the variance is low).  But I don't understand the relevance of the first sentence--"scaling is necessary" for what exactly?  Scaling isn't universally necessary.

Comment: It's true that scaling isn't universally necessary. It's necessary only if the features use different units (i.e. one feature is in meter while a different feature is in km). The reason is that the variance of a feature has as unit the square of the units of the variable itself (i.e. if a feature in m has a variance of 1000^2 the same feature converted to km will have var=1^2).

Answer (score 0):

I created an issue to request the documentation be clarified.  This is the response:

> Normalized and unnormalized data have valid uses cases in VarianceThreshold:
>
> - If you only want to use VarianceThreshold to remove constant features        then threshold=0 works regardless if the data was normalized.
> - If you want the threshold have the same meaning for features, then
>   normalizing makes sense.
>
> The example in the docstring is showcasing Use Case 1...
>
> *Source: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/23394*

I believe the second point is that a non-zero threshold only really makes sense if the features have been normalised (so they have the same scale) as stated by [prashanth](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/86202/prashanth)